# e.preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which rows are generated with a click event of an  element. Now, this works perfectly, the problem is with the delete part. For example I have already added 5 rows, when I click the delete button (the delete button is created through jQuery too on the addRow() click event), all rows added through the jQuery function are being deleted and the form is submitting event though I have an e.preventDefault() method called.

JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
        var counter = 2;            
        window.addRow = function addRow() {
            var newRow = $('<tr><td><label>'+ counter +'</label></td><td><textarea name="txtActionStep' + counter + '" style="width:300px; height: 50px; word-wrap:break-word;"></textarea></td><td valign="top"><input type="text" name="txtOwner' + counter + '"/></td><td><button class="delete">delete</button></td></tr>');
            counter++;                
            $('table.actionsteps-list').append( newRow );
        }

        $('table.actionsteps-list').on('click', '.delete', function(e){ 
          e.preventDefault(); // stops the page jumping to the top
          $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });


        function postForm() {
            var form = document.getElementById('actionStepsForm');
            document.getElementById('rowCount').value = counter-1;
            form.submit();
        }
```

HTML Code (the form itself):

```
<form name="actionStepsForm" id="actionStepsForm" action="add_reprocessing.php?action=add" method="post">
<table class="actionsteps-list" width="510">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" align="left">Action Steps</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Step #</td><td>Action Step</td><td>Owner</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>1</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="txtActionStep1" style="width:300px; height: 50px; word-wrap:break-word;"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" name="txtOwner1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="510">
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><a href="#" title="" onclick="addRow(); return false;">Add Action</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="postForm(); return false;" />
<input type="hidden" value="" id="rowCount" name="rowCount" />
</form>
```

Believe it or not, I've been stuck here for almost 3 days now. I can't find any fix online.  I don't what's wrong.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zc9Gw/?

Comment: A `<button>` without a `type` doesn't have a default action to prevent. And, may not even then -- a `click` of a `type="submit"` would become a `submit` event at the `<form>`.

Comment: Hi @j08691, yes, I know it works fine in jsfiddle.. I'm really lost about this one. Would the DOCTYPE and JQuery impact this one? Can you take a look at my code as a whole? I can send it to you via dropbox :|

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, I've tried putting `type="submit"` in the delete button but it showed same result

Comment: What happens if you `return false` in that same codeblock? That should prevent the event from bubbling up and triggering other handlers.

Comment: try to replace the hash (href="#") of the <a> with javascript:void(0);

Comment: do you have your code inside a document.ready function? jsfiddle does this automatically.

Comment: @andrew -- No, can you show me how to do it properly? The codes above are as is.

Comment: @aguas try the middle section $('table.....}); into a `$(function(){//here});`

Comment: @andrew -- Thanks! I did it already!

Comment: @aguas I posted it as an answer so you can accept if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
 $('table.actionsteps-list').on('click', '.delete', function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault(); // stops the page jumping to the top
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

into

```
$(function(){$('table.actionsteps-list').on('click', '.delete', function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault(); // stops the page jumping to the top
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
 )};
```